# URL redirect via apache

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I have gone through a lot of tutorials on apache,and could redirect few urls.
Though,there is this url for which I need to do a redirect and I couldn't.Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks !
Note: Making changes to httpd.conf

URL : https://example.com/common/webScript.jsp?path=/example/content/latest.rss?section=Insight%26type=Leaders 
 to https://example.com

As I have already configured my domain, Just need to redirect 
URL : **/common/webScript.jsp?path=/example/content/latest.rss?section=Insight%26type=Leaders** to  /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uri-path after "?" character are query strings, you need to check them with %{QUERY_STRING} ^path` or similar. Rough example:

```
# to capture uri-path with query string starting with "path..." 
# redirect it to /

# for 2.4 with If directive (most modern)
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#^path#">
    RedirectMatch ^ /
</If>


# or with mod_rewrite that works with 2.2 too    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^path
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L,QSD]
```

If you just want to redirect /common/webScript.jsp to / 
just do a simple:

```
RedirectMatch ^/common/webScript.jsp /
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! But I dont want to identify url with query string "path" but wanted to identify if the url starts with /common/webScript.jsp.   If the url starts with /common/webScript.jsp ,wanted to redirect to /

Comment: @ShailajaKrishnamurthy added a new option based on your comment.

Comment: HI @ezra-s , this is working fine ! Thanks !But in addition to the RewriteCond ,used RewriteRule and not RedirectMatch and it worked fine!

Comment: Use RewriteCond when you have a real condition you want to check and can only be done with RewriteCond, like for example, checking query string. Using RewriteCond and RewriteRule to redirect a simple uri-path is overkill.